# Shapes proportionally resize with window in SFML 2.X

Tags: c++, sfml

The code is off the tutorial on the SFML site. When I compile and run it the circle scales proportionally as the window is scaled by the user. I want the circle to stay a constant shape.

When the screen is re-sized, both the correct screen dimensions and the correct circle radius are printed to the console, but the  way the circle is drawn to the screen is definitely not what it claims to be. The circle is not visually distorted in any way, but looks as though it is being drawn with a different set of values as to what is printed to the console.

The `antialiasingLevel` makes no difference to the shape dawn, if that helps.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

int main()
{
    sf::ContextSettings settings;
    settings.antialiasingLevel = 8;

    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(200, 200), "Title", sf::Style::Default, settings);
    sf::CircleShape shape(100);
    shape.setFillColor(sf::Color::Green);

    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        sf::Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                window.close();
            else if (event.type == sf::Event::Resized)
            {
                std::cout << "resize: ("  << event.size.width << ',' << event.size.height << ") -> " << shape.getRadius() << std::endl;
            }
        }

        window.clear();
        window.draw(shape);
        window.display();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The tutorials cover this: [the resized event](http://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.2/window-events.php#the-resized-event) and [showing more when the window is resized](http://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.2/graphics-view.php#showing-more-when-the-window-is-resized)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The following line added in the resized event will correct the problem.

```
window.setView(sf::View(sf::FloatRect(0, 0, event.size.width, event.size.height)));
```

The issue seems to be that the view is not automatically scaled to fit the new resolution.

Comment: Might want to static_cast<float> the width and height. They are unsigned integers. FloatRect expects floats. Probably should write 0 as 0.0F as well.